# Editable name in a breadcrumb

Tags: breadcrumbs, inline-edit

I am searching for use cases that provides the user to edit the name of an asset in line, when is part of a breadcrumb.

Is that case exist somewhere? (Saas) please mention the brand so i can have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see with your idea is how to distinguish between clicking on the breadcrumb item to navigate and how to click on it to edit.

You could split the name into a separate label or add an edit pencil icon/button to allow editing the name.

[image: UI proposal]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But what if the editable part is not clickable- because it is the last part of the breadcrumbs , and you are actually in this page?

Comment: This sounds confusing to me. You have elements that look 100% alike, but clicking on them does different things. I would also be afraid that users would not find the edit functionality. Safest bet is to test with your users.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive does that, but only for the last (current) folder. There's a caret that brings a "Rename" option, which is made on a modal.

[image]